# Keep screen from moving to cursor when saving in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Whenever you save changes in a document (Ctrl+S, for instance), the screen moves to where the cursor is. Is it possible to disable this? It's quite annoying. I don't see any such option in `Tools -> Options -> Load/Save`, where one would expect to see it. Nor it is in `Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Writer`. Any idea how to change this behaviour? Haven't found a similar topic in this forum or elsewhere online.

Comment: Using LibreOffice 6.1.6.3 with default options this doesn't happen to me. When saving the file the window stays focused where it is and doesn't more to the cursor.

Comment: @bad_coder I have version 6.4.7.2. Not sure if have default options but certainly hasn't changed that setting, at least not consciously. :/

Comment: I tried search for the setting in the Writer and also googling for it but no luck, a good approach might be also asking on [the bugtracker](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/buglist.cgi?component=Writer&order=changeddate%20DESC%2Cbug_status%2Cpriority%2Cassigned_to%2Cbug_id&product=LibreOffice&query_format=advanced&resolution=---)